# Python Program to use the resources of systems over internet?

Tags: python, networking

i am fairly new to python , was wondering if i could remotely connect to another system over net , both the systems have different ISPs . can i write a program to connect to that system and use it resources , ofcourse with that systems permission.

PS: it kinda sounds like hacking into system without permission , but i have no intention of doing so .

Comment: What are __specifically__ are you trying to do?

Comment: -1: "connect to that system and use it resources" Could mean anything.  It's too vague to answer.

Comment: well to begin with , there is a small problem that when i am trying to chat with my frnd its kinda annoying that we will have to chat using an email client and again switch to code , this back and fro gets irritating at times . so i thought let me build some small program which allows me to connect to his system and we chat directly using terminal , well i am aware of tools like etherpad , but wanted to do of my own , even though it would be reinventing the wheel .

Comment: "well to begin with"... Doesn't make much sense.  "chat directly" should be clarified, explained -- with examples -- and should be part of the question.  Please **update** the question to contain specific details of what you're trying to do.  Please be specific.

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds a lot like RPC (Remote Procedure Calls). Python has libraries that handle RPC using XML to pass parameters and results (which frees you from dealing with binary format issues), which are [xmlrpclib](http://docs.python.org/library/xmlrpclib.html) on the client side and [SimpleXMLRPCServer](http://docs.python.org/library/simplexmlrpcserver.html) or [DocXMLRPCServer](http://docs.python.org/library/docxmlrpcserver.html) on the server end.

It's only one solution out of many, but it can be a starting point.

Comment: well what all parameters should i be aware of before doing so ,apart from ip address of the other system.

Comment: Rahul: Your question was rather vague, so we can only give you rather vague answers.

Comment: i apologise for that , but since my knowledge into the field is not that profound, i didnt know how to frame my question.

Comment: @Rahul just tell us exactly what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: @Rahul: What I'm getting at here is that you're not nearly to the point where you can even ask an answerable question.  I gave you those links so you can go read them and then say if they solve the problem you have, and if not, why not.

Comment: well to begin with , there is a small problem that when i am trying to chat with my frnd its kinda annoying that we will have to chat using an email client and again switch to code , this back and fro gets irritating at times . so i thought let me build some small program which allows me to connect to his system and we chat directly using terminal , well i am aware of tools like etherpad , but wanted to do of my own , even though it would be reinventing the wheel   PS: i am srry that i am posting this again in here

Comment: What you described is available as [YTalk and SSH](http://linuxdevcenter.com/pub/a/linux/2003/02/13/ssh_ytalk.html), at least.

Answer (score 0):

Also take a look at [pyro](http://www.xs4all.nl/~irmen/pyro3/)

EDIT: I recommend you read about [RPC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_procedure_call) and tell us is this what **YOU** want.

Comment: will it also work , i am working on systems over the internet , i mean 2 different systems with different ISPs and all .

Comment: @Rahul: The systems' presence on different ISPs actually doesn't really matter.  TCP/IP does not care if the endpoints are in the same room or different sides of the planet.  The differences between the computers at the two endpoints are far more important.